# Kryo setCopyTransient

Tags: java, serialization, deep-copy, kryo

I am trying to use the Kryo library to perform deep copying of objects, but I have a little problem. I'd like to deep-copy an object without transient variables. I know that I can use `setCopyTransient(false)` for `FieldSerializer` like so:

```
FieldSerializer<?> playerSerializer = new FieldSerializer<Player>(kryo, Player.class);
playerSerializer.setCopyTransient(false);
kryo.register(Player.class, playerSerializer);
```

but I would have to set a new `FieldSerializer` for every class. Can I get somehow a default `FieldSerilizer` from Kryo and set there `setCopyTransient(false)`? I tried something like this and similar solutions, but it doesn't do anything:

```
FieldSerializer<?> serilizer = (FieldSerializer<?>) kryo.getDefaultSerializer(FieldSerializer.class);
serilizer.setCopyTransient(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of kryo you are using. I am using 3.0.0 and my transient fields are not serialized.

Comment: I am using kryo version 3.0.3. Are you using kryo for deep-copy (`kryo.copy()` method)? Copying does not serialize to bytes and back. In normal serialization transient fields are omitted, but in cooping there are not.

Comment: @Sabriael No. I am using it to stream out data over network. I think copy may be doing it intentionally.